# ARE or IS in the sentence

Tags: there-is

"There is a kitchen and a bedroom in their house."
"There is a table and 14 chairs in my room."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a common grammar question that is dealt with on numerous online sites.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Maybe you could link to one then?